# If a space $Y$ is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces, then is $Y$ a $\sigma$-space?

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is a $\sigma$-space if $X$ has a $\sigma$-discrete network. If a space $Y$ is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces, then is $Y$ a $\sigma$-space?

I think it is. But I'm not sure. I don't make a silly mistake. So I post it as a question. Any help will be appreciated.

**Background:** Someone proved that $|X| \le 2^{d(X)s\Delta(X)}$. But I suspect it is not right. Since the Katetov extension of the discrete topoloty $\omega$  is separable and the cardinality is more than $\mathfrak c$. It is is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces. If the answer to the question is true, then it is a $\sigma$-space, and hence it has a $G^*_\delta$-diagonal, and hence $s\Delta(X)=\omega$. Then $|X| \le 2^{d(X)s\Delta(X)}$ is not true.

Comment: What’s the definition of $s\Delta$, and do you have any reference for the inequality?

Comment: It is [from Basile D, Bella A, Ridderbos G J. Weak extent, submetrizability and diagonal degrees\[J\]. arXiv preprint arXiv:1112.0883, 2011.][1]  [1]: http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0883

Comment: The inequality can be seen in the proposition 4.1 in this paper.

Comment: Okay; I’ll take a look, though it may take a day or two for me to think about it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You are very helpful. I will wait for your reponse.

Comment: @Paul The proof of the inequality looks OK to me (pretty standard argument). So it must be that $s\Delta(\kappa\omega) > \omega$

Comment: See my other answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/425437/4280 I think regularity is the key here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Henno has found the key to the question is regularity. It can be seen here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424123/is-this-proposition-correct-for-any-hausdorff-space-x-we-have-x-le-2dx. Thanks for your time. You are always helpful.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that that was where the problem was, but I hadn’t had a chance to think hard about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a space $Y$ is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces, then is $Y$ a $\sigma$-space?

It seems so. Suppose $Y=\bigcup Y_n$ is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces $Y_n$ of $Y$. For each $n$ the family $\mathcal Y_n=\{{y}:y\in Y_n\}$ is discrete. Then $\mathcal Y=\bigcup\mathcal Y_n$ is a $\sigma$-discrete network on $Y$.

> the Katetov extension of the discrete topology $\omega$  ... is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces.

Maybe this claim doesn’t hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is helpful for me. +1)

Comment: It’s definitely true that $\kappa\omega$ is a countable union of closed, discrete subspaces, since $\kappa\omega\setminus\omega$ is closed and discrete in $\kappa\omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Could you help me out this contradiction?