# Is this Proposition Correct? For any Hausdorff Space $X$ we have $|X| \le 2^{d(X)s\Delta(X)} $

Tags: general-topology

Is this proposition 4.1 right? It is from D. Basile, A. Bella, G J. Ridderbos, *Weak extent, submetrizability and diagonal degrees*. [arXiv:1112.0883, 2011.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0883)

[image: Proposition 4.1 from Basile, Bella, Ridderbos]

Comment: Is there some reason why you think it isn't?

Comment: I suspect it is not right. Since the Katetov extension of the discrete topoloty $\omega$  is separable and the cardinality is more than $\mathfrak c$. It is is a countable union of closed discrete subspaces. If the answer to the question is true, then it is a $\sigma$-space, and hence it has a $G^*_\delta$-diagonal, and hence $s\Delta(X)=\omega$. Then $|X| \le 2^{d(X)s\Delta(X)}$ is not true.

Comment: @Paul who says that $\kappa\omega$ is indeed the countable union of closed discrete subspaces? I don't see that.

Comment: As they mention $\kappa\omega$ as a counterexample to a stronger inequality, they probably know it has a $G_\delta$ diagonal but not a strong $G_\delta$ diagonal.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: See the last paragraph of this paper: Buzyakova R Z. Observations on spaces with zeroset or regular G δ-diagonals[J]. Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin, 2005, 46(3): 469-473.http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc0503/buzyakr.pdf

Comment: I realised that $\kappa\omega\setminus\omega$ is indeed closed and discrete, that plus the singleton subsets of $\omega$ show it is an $F_\sigma$-discrete space (a countable union of closed and discrete subspaces).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Then it has a contradiction. I am struggeling with it.

Comment: We know from the Buzyakova paper that $\kappa\omega$ does not have a regular $G_\delta$ diagonal. This would seem to be the "natural" way to have $s\Delta(X) = \omega$ for a space $X$. Where is your reference for a proof that a $\sigma$-space $X$ has $s\Delta(X) = \omega$, which is what causes your contradiction?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Theorem 4.6 of handbook of set theoretic topology shows that every $\sigma$-space has a $G^*_\delta$_diagonal. So $s\Delta(X)=\omega$.

Comment: @Paul $G^{\ast}_\delta$ diagonal means exactly $s\Delta(X) = \omega$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9311/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-paul)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Thanks for your help. However it is ten in night, I have to go home, otherwise my wife will be unhappy. So I hope I could continue the discussion with you tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (I do not have my copy of the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology at hand) that the problem is that $\kappa\omega$ is not $T_3$, just $T_2$. Recall that it is H-closed but not compact, so it cannot be $T_3$. A $\sigma$-space is a $T_3$ (so including $T_1$) space with a $\sigma$-discrete network. We do know that $\kappa\omega$ is a Hausdorff space with a $\sigma$-discrete network (namely the singletons, as $\kappa\omega\setminus\omega$ is closed and discrete, and so are the singleton subsets of $\omega$). So the proof that $\sigma$-spaces have a $G^{\ast}_\delta$-diagonal (a.k.a $s\Delta(\kappa\omega) = \omega$) need not apply.

So I'd check the definition (I think it assumes $T_3$ through-out the paper) and the proof for the $G^{\ast}_\delta$-diagonal as well, for (hidden) uses of regularity.

**Added later**

I checked in the Gruenhage chapter of the named Handbook and indeed $T_3$ is the "culprit". On page 426 the author already states that all spaces are assumed to be regular and $T_1$ unless otherwise stated. And the theorem that $\sigma$-spaces have a $G^{\ast}_\delta$ diagonal uses theorem 2.11, which states that submetacompact spaces with a $G_\delta$ diagonal have a $G^{\ast}_\delta$ diagonal. We already know that $\kappa\omega$ does have indeed have a $G_\delta$ diagonal and it also subparacompact trivially (the singletons form $\sigma$-discrete closed refinement of any open cover, which is what is needed for this property) and so submetacompact (I think that this implication does not use regularity, going by Burke's chapter in the Handbook; otherwise we'd only have found *another* use of regularity). And indeed the proof of 2.11 (which is in lemma 2.12 in essence) makes have use of regularity explicitly (p. 433).

So $\kappa\omega$ is a nice example of a subparacompact (possibly also submetacompact, see p. 370 in the diagram) Hausdorff space with a $G_\delta$ diagonal that does not have a $G^{\ast}_\delta$ diagonal, showing that indeed $T_3$ is essential in this statement.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me out this question. It looks very clear to me!